# Focus on object issue

Tags: modeling

When I focus on object it's not focusing on the object it is focusing on the other side. I've checked normals and applied rotation and scale but it's not working.

Here's the link - https://drive.google.com/file/d/16qdmaQ8Twyl8RidDldqD3PbZpaxlpDs4/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: What kind of focusing do you mean? Framing the selected object in the viewport or the focus distance in the camera's depth of field settings? Anyway, it takes into account the origin point of the object for these things. If you're talking about something different please clarify this in your question and maybe add screenshots that show the issue and the settings.

Comment: framing the selected object

Comment: Well then, please edit your question and show how your object looks like so that this makes a proper answerable question. Show us what you have selected, what happens when you try to frame on selected etc., otherwise this is all just guesswork.

Comment: i've provided the link you can check

Comment: What kind of Blender version is this? The pie menu looks different to my 3.5.1 version and my 2.93 version - and yours says "View Selected"... since 2.8+ this is called "Frame Selected".

Comment: i have 3.5.0. It works fine in other projects or in other file and also works well in shading tab. But only in this project specifically in Layout Tab this creates problem. I dont know if i tweaked any of the setting.

Comment: Anyways thank you so much for helping me out.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.